# Softbody is clipping and shrinking when it comes in contact with an object (with collision enabled)

Tags: modeling, animation

I've recently been trying to make a softbody animation, and I have ramps that the ball falls down into. It rolls down fine, but when it reaches the end of it, the ball immediately shrinks and is attracted to the object. The ramp has collision enabled, I have tried recalculating normals, and changing the incline and rebaking it, but nothing seems to work.[image: The ball right before contact]

[image: The ball a couple of frames after contact]

The ball just seems to stay and then shrink a little bit, and will not just hop over the cylinder like it should.

Comment: Try changing the the collision type of the ramp from Convex Hull to Mesh

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the *inner thickness* of your collision object is too high and thus surmounts the *outer thickness*, effectively pulling every softbody-vertex into the collision object.
As far as I know the thickness values are actually in meters, if you didn't know that already.

Comment: Exactly this - the Inner of the opposite side of the cylinder at the bottom of the ramp will project out of the surface and will “grab” and soft body vertices that stray too close. The solution is to reduce the Inner collision bounds. Also worthwhile to Apply Scale on all meshes involved in the simulation and collision since odd scale after resizing can produce unexpected results.